# spark cluster performance decreases by adding more nodes

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql, apache-zeppelin, spark-cassandra-connector

I have a large data set of 1B records and want to run analytics using Apache spark because of the scaling it provides, but I am seeing an anti pattern here. The more nodes I add to spark cluster, completion time increases. Data store is Cassandra, and queries are run by Zeppelin. I have tried many different queries but even a simple query of `dataframe.count()` behaves like this.

Here is the zeppelin notebook, temp table has 18M records

```
val df = sqlContext
  .read
  .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
  .options(Map( "table" -> "temp", "keyspace" -> "mykeyspace"))
  .load().cache()
df.registerTempTable("table")

%sql 
SELECT first(devid),date,count(1) FROM table group by date,rtu order by date
```

when tested against different no. of spark worker nodes these were the results

```
+-------------+---------------+
| Spark Nodes |      Time     |
+-------------+---------------+
| 1 node      | 17 min 59 sec |
| 2 nodes     | 12 min 51 sec |
| 3 nodes     | 15 min 49 sec |
| 4 nodes     | 22 min 58 sec |
+-------------+---------------+
```

Increasing the no. of nodes decreases performance. which should not happen as it defeats the purpose of using Spark.

if you want me to run any query or further info about the setup please ask.
Any cues on why this is happening would be very helpful, been stuck on this for two days now. Thank you for your time.

**versions**

> Zeppelin: 0.7.1, Spark: 2.1.0, Cassandra: 2.2.9, Connector: datastax:spark-cassandra-connector:2.0.1-s_2.11

**Spark cluster specs**

> 6 vCPUs, 32 GB memory = 1 node

**Cassandra + Zeppelin server specs**

> 8 vCPUs, 52 GB memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to consider is that at a certain point you may be overwhelming the Cassandra Cluster with requests. Without also scaling the Cassandra side of the equation you could easily see diminishing returns as C* ends up spending too much time rejecting requests.

This is basically the Man-month fallacy. Just because you can throw more workers at a problem does not necessarily mean the project can be done faster.

It would be extremely beneficial for you to benchmark the different parts of your query separately. Currently as you have it setup the entire set of data is cache on the read which adds additional slowness if you are benchmarking a single request.

You should benchmark in isolation

- Reading from C* without caching (Simply count directly from C*)
- The Cost of caching (Count after caching)
- The cost of the shuffle query you are running (From cache run query)

Then you can figure out where your bottlenecks are and Scale appropriately.

Comment: Thank you @RussS, I ran some tests, count using cqlsh is taking 54 minutes while using spark (2 nodes) it takes 14 minutes. so bottle neck is cassandra? or is spark in general faster than cassandra?

Comment: In general, most spark things are faster than Cassandra. There are exceptions

Comment: why is that? can you point me to some articles on this? my single node spark is faster than single node cassandra. i would love to know why.

Comment: Saying one is faster is probably thinking about it wrong. They are two different things doing different jobs. Cassandra is a database which is constantly accessing the hardisk. Spark is an analytics platform that can be doing almost anything. This is kind of like asking why is the monitor faster at displaying text than your printer?

Comment: Any references, count is quite a basic query, and while Spark can do stuff in memory, count implies no benefit of caching.

Comment: Caching is not part of this. Perhaps another analogy. You have a Tape Driver reading 200 bytes a second and you hook it up to  a 4 ghz 16 core processor. You add a second processor in the hopes that you will be able to process data faster. This doesn't work because your bottleneck is *not* the processor, its the fact that the data source is only providing information at 200 bytes a second. The only way to increase your processing speed is to add another tape drive.

Count essentially takes none of your processing power(Spark) so you are stuck waiting for data (Cassandra).

Comment: thanks, that makes a lot of sense. Although still the main observation of @junaid that its actually slower to count via cqlsh implies some sort of suboptimal implementation by the cassandra cli?